# AdminLTE Project integrating with Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, integration

I am trying to integrate AdminLTE project in my java maven project. 
https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE

I have downloaded the code but am not sure where to start integrating as I am new to javascript and frontend development. I am bit confused looking at the project structure as how to map it to my java project.

Is there any way I can port this in some new dynamic java maven project and then start building my backend component accordingly.

Pardon me if this question sounds stupid but I do not have much idea about frontend development.